# How to get latest date using Power Query Editor in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have a dataset which have 3 attributes.

[image]

The requirement is to create a new column which should have the latest date from the "Date" column.
This should be a dynamic approach because in every refresh the dataset may change and I want the latest date should also get change in the new column after the refresh.

I have to create this in Power Query Editor of Power BI.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Check this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XEbwaPxXTUw

in short words:

1. add custom column
2. in colum definition type formula
   `=List.Max(#"your_last_step_name"[Date])`